# Is there any way to launch an app into a "modal view"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get an intro to be the first thing a user sees when they launch the app, and when they're done with the intro, it will be dismissed with the modal dismiss animation. Is there any way to dismiss the initial view controller in that way, or do I have to create a custom animation?

Comment: Better add Intro as Subview in InitialViewController, and add animation like dismiss when done...

Comment: @iphonic Are you suggesting I implement my own animation?

Comment: Yes, as you won't be able to dismiss, initialviewcontroller, another option is that you can present the `IntroViewController` as modal in `viewWillAppear` method of `initialViewController`. Try this, if it works well all good for you, but you will need to add a check that the intro doesn't present again on calling `viewWillAppear` of `initialViewController`.

Comment: @iphonic Your second suggestion didn't work, I get `Attempt to present <IntroTest.IntroViewController: 0x7fbe8389cb40> on <IntroTest.ViewController: 0x7fbe82425160> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` But what's to be expected, it seems a little hacky. Thanks anyway, I'll look into your first suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to display the actual initialViewController as usual, and when that loads, present the modal view overtop of it without an animation.

```
present(modalIntroView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Even though it's two years later, I still very much appreciate that you took the time to answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. And I figure if you don’t need it anymore, someone may find it useful